# Div text inheriting alignment from sibling element

Tags: html, css, dom, text-align

I am trying to adjust the horizontal alignment of text in a `div` element so that it is left with a bit of padding within that element (Image 'Desired Look' below).  It seems to be aligning to the content of the preceding sibling `div` (Image 'Current Look' below).  I suspect the solution is somewhere in range of using the right `display` property type but I've been fumbling with it for hours and could use some guidance.

[JsFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/Sec_Dev_WM/oq0Lwpt3/10/)

**Current Look**
[image: Current Look]

**Desired Look**
[image: Desired Look]

**CSS/HTML**

```css
/* Table Tabs */

div.Table_control {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 10px 0px 0px 15px;
}

div.DtTabs {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

div.Table_control * {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

div.DtTab_text {
  border-radius: 15px 15px 0px 0px;
  border-color: #880015;
  background: #ff4d67;
  bottom: 7px;
  color: #FFF;
  font-family: "Segoe UI", "Segoe", Tahoma, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 21px;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 190px;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 2px #000;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

div.DtTab_text.ActiveScope {
  border-radius: 15px 15px 0px 0px;
  border-collapse: separate;
  bottom: 8px;
  background: #880015;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 400;
  width: 200px;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 3px #000;
}

div.DtControls {
  text-align: right;
}

div.dataTables_length,
div.dataTables_filter,
div.DtTabs>* {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

div.dataTables_filter {
  padding-right: 5px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

div.dataTables_length {
  margin-right: 5px;
}


/* DataTable Labels */


/* DataTable Labels */

div.DtLabel {
  width: inherit;
  background: #880015;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-radius: 10px 0px 0px 0px;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  font-family: "Segoe UI", "Segoe", Tahoma, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14pt;
  height: auto;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  text-align: left;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 3px #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="Table_control">
  <div class="DtTabs">
    <div class="DtTab_text ActiveScope">Administrators
      <a class="DtTab_Ext"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="DtTab_text">APT Group
      <a class="DtTab_Ext"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="DtTab_text">IT
      <a class="DtTab_Ext"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="DtControls">
    <div class="dataTables_filter" id="AdminUnrankedSRs_filter"><label>Search:<input aria-controls="AdminUnrankedSRs" type="search" placeholder=""></label></div>
    <div class="dataTables_length" id="AdminUnrankedSRs_length"><label>Show <select name="AdminUnrankedSRs_length" aria-controls="AdminUnrankedSRs">
          <option value="5">5</option>
          <option value="10">10</option>
          <option value="25">25</option>
          <option value="100">100</option>
        </select> entries</label></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="DtLabel">UNRANKED</div>
```

Comment: Please add meaningful code. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing — otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a [Minimal, Reproducible example (or MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: try to add unrank word maybe inside a p or span

Comment: Seems to me that your `float: left` stuff is the problem.  If, for example, you add an element with `clear: left` just above the "UNRANKED" div then you'll see the element looks closer to what you expect.  Were it me I would avoid floating altogether.  Modern CSS gives much better control.

Comment: Sorry Liaf.  I thought that the extraction of code from my site into a jsFiddle example would suffice for meaningful code.  I can certainly add it directly into the question if that is more proper.

Comment: That is a useful hint avejidah.  It seems to solve the stated problem but adds a new one where the sibling divs are separated but I suspect I can work that out.